# UIImages Show Up On Simulator But Not Device

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, uiimage

I'm using a Web Service that returns images which I put into a tableviewcell. I can see these images on the iPhone simulator, but they don't show up on the device. Here is the code for me getting the image:

```
NSString *imgurlString = bestPageDictionary[@"image_url"];
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:imgurlString];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
UIImage *zeeimageForCell = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
[dVC setItemDisplayImage:zeeimageForCell];
```

Comment: Can you post the setItemDisplayImage method ?

Comment: there is no setItemDisplayImage method. But there is an image property i have in my detailViewController called itemDisplayImage

Comment: Can you open that image in Safari in device and see if it gets loaded. It could be possible that a firewall is blocking it ...

Comment: Just wait..Maybe it's just loading it rather slowly on the device?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are downloading image from calling a URL. Might be connection lost or data lost.  Please download it via using any third party such [EGOImageLoading](https://github.com/enormego/EGOImageLoading)UIImageView or [sdWebImageview](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage).